# How to get more than 20 Instagram locations via API?

Tags: json, instagram, instagram-api

Using

```
"https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat={LATITUDE}&lng={LONGITUDE}&access_token={ACCESS-TOKEN}"
```

I only seem to be able to get 20 results, although I can tell there are more than that many locations by looking on the Instagram app. There is no pagination information provided, and adding

```
&dist={DISTANCE}
```

does not seem to have any effect on the results whatsoever.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the best solution I found was to get the most recent media within a certain radius, using:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat={LATITUDE}&lng={LONGITUDE}&distance={DISTANCE}&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&count={COUNT}`

then query the locations each of those photos were from (having removed duplicates) to get more images from each location, using:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/{LOCATION_ID}/media/recent?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}`

This is the only way I could find to get many images from more than 20 locations! Basically, I'm performing a location search through the media by location search.

Answer (score -2):

[api endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

You have to call the url given inside pagination key to get more results

Comment: Yes, thank you for your response, but this endpoint does not seem to give the pagination key.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. @Jan

Comment: have you tried setting the distance to its max value? other than that you have to query a multiple times then compare your payload with each other and then make a final one with the uniques.

Comment: Yes, I tried distance values including 0, 50, 100, 200, 500, and 750 (and not including distance in the call at all), and all returned the same 20 (closest, I think) locations.